# (typeof (someClass) - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to learn my first OOP language C# and am finding it difficult to understand some concepts.

In the code below, What is happening with the (typeof (MySerializer)) actually doing? I've read the [msdn documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx), but am not clear on what they are talking about. The only thing I know if happening is there is a log being created.

```
public static class MySerializer
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (MySerializer)); ///


    } 


 public static T Deserialize<T>(string input)
```

Comment: It's getting the Type of MySerializer and it's handing it to GetLogger(). Apparently GetLogger would like a Type. You need to read the docs for GetLogger first.

Comment: Why so many down votes, legitimate question.

Comment: Reflection is probably something you're better off getting involved with *after* you pick up on the basics of C# (since you say you're learning). That means, I think you're better off not paying attention to what `typeof` does just yet. It's one of the more advanced areas of C#, or actually .NET. (Edit: to clarify, this is not an answer to your question about downvotes. I didn't vote on your question.)

Comment: @Mark - No, questions that ask for very basic concepts are off topic here. It's not a tutorial site. This one might be on the edge but who knows, some downvotes could also be for your formatting.

Comment: @hvd, I work as a front end developer, and am learning the basic, it just happens that I work with a team of senior programmers, and am fortunate enough to be able to reference the way things are done in real applications. But you're right, occasionally things are being done that are def. more advance than I should be working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetLogger(..)` method takes a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (A class, interface, etc) as it's parameter. The [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator will return the type of object, in this case `MySerializer`, as a `System.Type`.